# kotlinc compile multiple files/dependencies/imports

Tags: kotlin, kotlinc

I want to compile a kotlin file with a dependency / import

package_a.kt

```kotlin
// file: package_a.kt
package package_a

fun function_from_package_a(){
    println(" hurray function_from_package_a was called ! ")
}
```

main.kt

```kotlin
// file: main.kt

import package_a.*

fun main() {
    
    function_from_package_a();

    println("main function  was executed")
}
```

compiling is working with

```
$ kotlinc package_a.kt -d package_a.jar               
$ kotlinc main.kt -classpath package_a.jar -d main.jar
```

but when i run the main.jar with java, i will get an error:

```
$ java -jar main.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: package_a/Package_aKt
        at MainKt.main(main.kt:8)
        at MainKt.main(main.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package_a.Package_aKt
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 2 more
```

does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

When you compile the main class with the command:

```
kotlinc main.kt -classpath package_a.jar -d main.jar
```

the resulting `main.jar` only contains the main class object.  It does not contain the objects in the `package_a` package.  The `-classpath` option to `kotlinc` only allows symbols to be resolved during compilation.  It doesn't cause anything else to be included in the resulting `main.jar` file.

Therefore, when you execute:

```
java -jar main.jar
```

Java does not know where to get the contents of the `package_a` package.

You might then think that this would work:

```
java -classpath package_a.jar -jar main.jar
```

but this does not work either, because when you specify that Java execute a jar file, all directives for finding dependent objects, be they in the jar file or elsewhere, have to come from the jar file itself.  The `-classpath` option is ignored when the `-jar` option is used.

UPDATE: I saw the OPs posted answer only after posting my own.  That alternate way of running the code works because the `-jar` option is not being used, and so the `-classpath` option is not ignored, and so the indicated command tells Java what to execute and also tells it where to find all of the necessary class files.

NOTE: No changes were necessary to the original source files.  The main class does not need to be in a named package to be able to refer to it on the command line.  This command would have executed the code in its original form:

```
java -cp main.jar:package_a.jar MainKt
```

Another option would be to include the dependent package in the `main.jar` file.  I tried this, and it works fine.  It's a bit involved, as you have to get the manifest right so that Java knows which class to execute. Because the OP has found another way, I won't elaborate here.

Comment: It would be nice/helpful to see the "dependent package" solution with the manifest that you mention here.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution for the problem

i changed my main.kt to

```kotlin
// file: main.kt
package test

import package_a.*

fun main() {
    
    function_from_package_a();

    println("main function  was executed")
}
```

and then i can run it with

```
java -cp main.jar:package_a.jar test.MainKt
```

Comment: I'm glad you found an acceptable answer.  Maybe you'll still find my answer valuable to better understand just what is going on here.